# How to debug Dash in VS code within a subfolder (not at root)

Tags: plotly-dash, vscode-debugger

As part of the debugging of Dash application, I have followed the vs code application set up.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Dash",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/run.py",
            "args": ["run_server"],
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "run",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

This works well. However, if the run file is in the test folder and I adapt the config as:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Dash",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test/run.py",
            "args": ["run_server"],
            "env": {
                "FLASK_APP": "test.run",
                "FLASK_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

It gives a no module run after the launch of the dash app and nothing is possible to debug. Is there a specific trick? Thanks!

I tried the above and adapting the flask_app naming.